# Split Bash String That Contain '&&'

Tags: string, bash, split, ampersand

I have a bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

params="path=/me & you/folder/file.json&&user=Bob"
splitParams=(${params//&&/ })

for i in "${!splitParams[@]}"
do
    echo "$i: ${splitParams[i]}"
done
```

It produces:

```
0: path=/me
1: &
2: you/folder/file.json
3: user=Bob
```

But when I type em in shell:

```
➜  params="path=/me & you/folder/file.json&&user=Bob"
➜  splitParams=(${params//&&/ })
➜  echo $splitParams
path=/me & you/folder/file.json user=Bob
```

I expect the output from script is like when I typed in shell:

```
0: path=/me & you/folder/file.json
1: user=Bob
```

Comment: The line `splitParams=(${params//&&/ })` first replaces all `&&` with a space and than tokenizes/splits the string at every whitespace into an array. The same happens both in the script as well as the command line. Printing this array directly (like you do on the command line) will join all elements with a single space on a single line. Looping over the array (like you do in the script) will print every element on a separate line, of course.

Comment: The loop from the script can be typed in the command line like this: `for i in "${!splitParams[@]}"; do echo "$i: ${splitParams[$i]}"; done`. By the way, there is an error in the script, it should be `"$i: ${splitParams[$i]}"` instead of `"$i: ${splitParams[i]}"`.

Answer (score 1):

`echo $splitParams` only prints the first element. Use `declare -p` to see exactly what's in the array:

```
$ declare -p splitParams
declare -a splitParams=([0]="path=/me" [1]="&" [2]="you/folder/file.json" [3]="user=Bob")
```

So now how can you split the string at `&&` but not have whitespace mess things up? Well, relying on the shell to do it is error-prone. Changing `&&` into spaces and splitting on spaces runs into trouble when the input string already contains spaces.

A better way to do it is to change the delimiters into newlines. Then instead of using `array=($string)` to break `$string` apart, use `readarray` so spaces don't trigger splitting, only newlines.

```
$ readarray -t splitParams < <(sed 's/&&/\n/g' <<< "$params")
$ declare -p splitParams
declare -a splitParams=([0]="path=/me & you/folder/file.json" [1]="user=Bob")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP '(?<=^|&&).*?(?=&&|$)' <<< "path=/me & you/folder/file.json&&user=Bob"
```

prints:

```
path=/me & you/folder/file.json
user=Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```
params="path=/me & you/folder/file.json&&user=Bob"
while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0'
do
  splitParams+=("$REPLY")
done < <(echo "${params}" | awk -F'&&' '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s\0",$i); }')

for i in "${!splitParams[@]}"
do
    echo "$i: ${splitParams[i]}"
done
```

Output:

```
0: path=/me & you/folder/file.json
1: user=Bob
```

Comment: Actually there are not used any GNU AWK extensions in my code. And is comaptible with UNIX awk --traditional

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk for that purpose, but remember that splitParams can not be accessible outside of the awk. We will use awk's split function:

> split([String to be proccessed], [Array for results], [Delimeter])

```
#!/bin/bash
params="path=/me & you/folder/file.json && user=Bob"
awk -F: '{split($0, splitParams, "&&"); print splitParams[1] "\n"splitParams[2]}' <<< $params
```

Output:

```
 path=/me & you/folder/file.json
  user=Bob
```